# cloning github repo to colab

Tags: git-clone, google-colaboratory

I ran this in Colab as in 1st Google page:

```
! git clone https://github.com/karoldem/dh/blob/master/dh.ipynb


Cloning into 'dh.ipynb'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/karoldem/dh/blob/master/dh.ipynb/' not found
```

you can check, that the repo under that link does exist, so what on the Earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to clone a single file from that repository. You have to specify the repository itself, which is `https://github.com/karoldem/dh.git`

Comment: @Progman
Thank, and how do I create an instance of class dh, because I tried various ways and I can't.

! git clone https://github.com/karoldem/dh.git
import dh
dh(3)

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
!git clone https://github.com/karoldem/dh
```

git clone clones repository so that path should be for repository.

Comment: I think you meant `git clone` not `!git clone`

Comment: I wrote for colab.. in others yup you can use git only